Change graph aesthetics in ggplot (black outline with colour fill)
I am trying to format this graph for my thesis. This code works, but what I want is the outline of the graph to be black, with the colour filling the boxes, but I cannot for the life of me get it to do it.
ggboxplot(Combined_Exeter_no_anomalies, x = "Histology", y = c("AMH", "CYP19", "FOXL2","CYP17"), 
ylab = "Relative Gene Expression" , palette = c("#00AFBB", "#008000", "#E7B800", "#FC4E07"), merge= TRUE)

This is my graph so far
Most examples I can find simply tell R to fill = "variable", but as I have four variables to colour, it does not seem to like this and binding the columns together also has not worked. Any thoughts?
This is what I am aiming to achieve
